# New to ML: How to store return values of type a* a* a*

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I have a program that returns int*int

(Example for illustration purposes):
fun program(a,b) = (1,2)

I want to do something along the lines:

> fun program(a,b)
>      if a = 0 then (1,2)
>      else
>      val x,y = program(a-1,b)
>      return (x-1, y)

Basically, I want to manipulate the tuple that is returned, and then return a modification of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works almost exactly as you wrote it, except that your syntax is a bit off:

```
fun program(a,b) =
  if a = 0 then (1,2)
  else
    let val (x,y) = program(a-1,b) in
      (x-1, y)
    end
```

Specifically:

1. Functions are defined by `fun f args = body` - you left out the `=`.
2. Variables are bound with  `let val foo = bar in baz end`.
3. There is no return keyword in sml.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to suggest that while you *need* to return a type `t : int * int`, you can *atleast* **curry** the inputs to your function from : `int * int = int -> int`. If you need to turn this back, you can always **uncurry**. I'd suggest writing the function as :

```
fun program a b =
   if a = 0 
   then (1,2)
   else
       let
           val (x,y) = program (a - 1) b
       in
           (x - 1, y)
       end
```

The type of this function is : `int -> int -> (int * int)`